# Using private bitbucket repos using auth token

Tags: composer-php

Usually I would use Satis for this but currently I don't have access so trying to include a dependency using an auth token with read access. My composer.json reads the following;

```
"repositories": {
    "vendor/package": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://bitbucket.org:vendor/package.git",
        "options":  {
            "http": {
                "header": [
                    "Authorization: Bearer ....UYvn4p-YCPasH0wuS9Ny42UAwISYI..."
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

When doing the update it still asks me for login credentials. Can anyone point me in the right direction?